# Using a function to create multiple subsets in a loop

Tags: r, function, loops, subset, assign

I'm trying to create a loop for deleting the same column of multiple data frames, and I want to assign its original name to the new df resulted.

```
id_externo_out<-function(x){
  result<-
    subset(x, select=-2)%>%
    data.frame()
  return(result)
}

contratos_id_ext_out<-c('cascada_contratos1-2017','cascada_contratos2-2017','cascada_contratos1-2018','cascada_contratos2-2018')
contratos_id_ext_out

for(i in length(contratos_id_ext_out)){
  assign(contratos_id_ext_out[i],
         id_externo_out(contratos_id_ext_out[i]))

}
```

And it's giving me back this error:

```
 Error in subset.default(x, select = -2) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: If you `debug(id_externo_out)` (and run your `for` loop), I think you'll find that `x` is just a string, such as `"\`cascada_contratos1-2017.csv\`"`. If you want data from a CSV file, you need to read it in, there's no inference that it should read in the data from a file of the same name as the object's value.

Comment: Suggestion: if each of the files is a similar structure, then it is often better to read them in into a `list` of frames. The assumption is that if you do something to one of the frames, you'll do it to all of them; in which case, `alldat <- lapply(contratos_id_ext_out, function(fn) id_externo_out(read.csv(fn)))`. (C.f. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272)

Comment: Thank you. But the name of the df is finishin .csv. It's pretty confusing, excuse me.

Comment: The only data type we see is `contratos_id_ext_out`, which is a `character` vector. If that is intended to be an indirect reference to variable names, then you need to be clear about that in your question, and state either *how* that indirect reference is actually working in your code, or the fact that you don't know how to make that happen. (For example, you might need to be using `get`.)

Comment: I want contratos_id_ext_out to be the names of the data frames that are already in the environoment. To run the loop only on those df with the names of contratos_id_ext_out and name them with the same name that in the beggining.

Comment: Okay. Look up `get`, it retrieves an object based on a character string of the object name (in a specific environment). Having said that, I strongly feel that the use of `get` and `assign` indicate likely flawed (fragile, unreproducible) approaches. I really think looking at that link I provided will give some indication of why list-of-frames is a good way to approach problems like this.